# Rails 5 - ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant PeopleController)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting this routing error in my Heroku logs and I am unsure how to fix it. I followed the instructions [seen here](https://richonrails.com/articles/mongodb-and-rails).

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :people, except: [:show]

  root to: "people#index"
end
```

The controller people_controller.rb:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)

    if @person.save
      redirect_to people_path, notice: "The person has been created!" and return
    end
    render 'new'
  end

  def edit
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])

    if @person.update_attributes(person_params)
      redirect_to people_path, notice: "#{@person.first_name} #{@person.last_name} has been updated!" and return
    end

    render 'edit'
  end

  def destroy
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    @person.destroy

    redirect_to people_path, notice: "#{@person.first_name} #{@person.last_name} has been deleted!" and return
  end
private
  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :notes)
  end
end
```

In case it's needed, here's person.rb model:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :notes, type: String
end
```

Comment: What's the file name? Rails requires file name to match the class name.

Comment: File name is people_controller.rb, and the model is person.rb.

Comment: Please post an excerpt from your logfile containing this routing error.

Comment: Is it working locally?

Answer (score 0):

Run command:

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

and check routes for people.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried exactly the same thing you did on my environment and it works perfectly. I could not find anything wrong with the code.

Apart from looking at your file structure on your server. (could be files are in the wrong folder).

I am with @puneet18, does it work locally for you?

Comment: It was working locally but not on Heroku. I realised that git hadn't added a bunch of files. I used git commit -am command but it only seems to work when I do git add -A and then git push -m seperately. Seems like a silly mistake in retrospect.

Comment: So you have it sorted now?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I hadn't staged my files in Git properly so it wasn't pushing all my changes to Heroku. Whoops! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯